# Moving CGPaths by x,y pixels?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

Is there a way to move a path on screen by (x,y) pixels using directly a CGPathRef instead of walking through its points and lines again in drawRect method? I want to be reusing my old CGPathRef when I want to move it on screen instead of recreating it with new pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you could just translate the drawing context via [CGContextTranslateCTM](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextTranslateCTM) before drawing your path (then restore the old context, either with push/popping contexts, or inverting the translation). You might also like [CGPathApply](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathApply), which will call a function for every path element in the path (so you can translate the points by hand).

Comment: first of all my path just contains points and lines and I use only the functions ..MoveToPoint and ..AddLineToPoint methods to draw them. From the performance perspective does it differ to perform a for loop with the points of the path than using CGPathApply method?